# How to Order by ForeignKey of parent Model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I have 2 models:

**Model User**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, related_name='checkin', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**Model Location**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How can I **order Location by number of checkin of User Model**?

I tried this but not success:

`Location.objects.annotate(checkin_count=Count('user')).order_by('-checkin_count')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a related_name, you should use that in your annotate call.

```
Location.objects.annotate(checkin_count=Count('checkin')).order_by('-checkin_count')
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll pick you the best answer!